# Extract lists from a list in dictionary

Tags: python

Suppose I have this dictionary:

```
self.dict = {'A':[[10, 20],[23,76,76],[23,655,54]], 'B':[30, 40, 50], 'C':[60, 100]}
```

Where the key `'A'` is a list of lists. I want to get only the first 2 lists of 'A', i.e. `[10, 20],[23,76,76]`. I tried the idea of looping but it does not work well. :

```
class T(object):
    def __init__(self):
            self.dict = {'A':[[10, 20],[23,76,76],[23,655,54]], 'B':[30, 40, 50], 'C':[60, 100]}

        def output(self):
            for i in self.dict:
                for j in self.dict[i]:
                        first_two_lists = j
                    print ("%s" % (first_two_lists))

if __name__ == '__main__':
        T().output()
```

How can I get that ?

Comment: Sorry for mistake. it is fixed

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> d = {'A':[[10, 20],[23,76,76],[23,655,54]], 'B':[30, 40, 50], 'C':[60, 100]}
>>> d['A'][:2]
[[10, 20], [23, 76, 76]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Using list slicing:

```
>>> d = {'A':[[10, 20],[23,76,76],[23,655,54]], 'B':[30, 40, 50], 'C':[60, 100]}
>>> d.get('A')[:2]
[[10, 20], [23, 76, 76]]
```